# get results without form submit

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Can someone help me how to get amount, currency and show results without form submit etc... So when I typing numbers it shows automatic results and when I change currency results changes. Thanks :)

```
const toCurrency = (n, curr, LanguageFormat = undefined) =>
Intl.NumberFormat(LanguageFormat, { style: 'currency', currency: curr }).format(n);

const userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += toCurrency(getAmount, 'getCurrency', 'userLang');
```

Whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/dvx2z1n3/36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select your input html element, and add an event to it.

```
var amount      = document.getElementById("amount");
```

Set up a Convert function to convert the input value to the desired currency:

```
Convert = (event) => {
  // you can work with event
  // your code to convert...
}
```

You already wrote it. And add an event to it:

```
amount.addEventListener('input', Convert(event));
```

After you have the converted amount, you can do it anything you want, like display it on somewhere. Select a html element add new value to it with the .innerHTML function.